# Compare columns from two data frames and modify the original data frame in consequence

Tags: r, merge, comparison

I have two dataframes :

df1 :

```
k1  k2       k3         k4
1   Alfred   Hitchcock  0
2   Claude   Renoir     0
3   Jean     Renoir     0
4   Louis    Mallet     0
5   Louis    Jouvet     0
```

and df2 :

```
k1  k2       k3 
1   Paul     Newman
2   Alfred   Hitchcock
3   Ernst    Jünger
```

I'd like to find a way in order to compare the k2 and k3 columns of my two data frames.
In case there is a duplicated item, relatively to k2 and k3, from df1 to df2 (here the first entry of df1 "Alfred"/"Hitchcock" matches with the 2nd entry of df2), I'd like to update the k4. I'd like this result :

```
k1  k2       k3         k4
1   Alfred   Hitchcock  1
2   Claude   Renoir     0
3   Jean     Renoir     0
4   Louis    Mallet     0
5   Louis    Jouvet     0
```

I've thought about using simple instruction, like :

```
df1$k4 [df1$k2 %in% df2$k2 & df1$k3 %in% df2$k3] <- 1
```

but it's not working.
I've also thought about using merge() instructions, but it doesn't seem to be able to help me (I don't particularly need to merge my data frames).

I think I can handle it with SQL, but with R in can't... I've tried sqldf but it doesn't work with OUTER and FULL JOIN.

P.S. : and as my data frames are really huge, I've tried not to use loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** Try this:

```
transform(df1, k4 = k4 + paste(k2, k3) %in% paste(df2$k2, df2$k3))
```

**(2)** or this:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select df1.k1, k2, k3, k4 + (df2.k1 is not null) k4 
       from df1 left join df2 
       using (k2, k3)")
```

giving:

```
  k1     k2        k3 k4
1  1 Alfred Hitchcock  1
2  2 Claude    Renoir  0
3  3   Jean    Renoir  0
4  4  Louis    Mallet  0
5  5  Louis    Jouvet  0
```

UPDATE: Added a second solution.